# What does the annotations do exactly in Android at compile time?

Tags: android

1. @SuppressWarnings("unsued")
2. @Override
3. @SuppressLint({ "InflateParams", "SimpleDateFormat" })

I don't get why we need to declare annotations.

Comment: I don't get why we need to declare annotations?

Comment: [@SuppressWarnings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html), [@Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html), [@SuppressLint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/SuppressLint.html) - did you read the respective documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to facilitate the writing and the maintenance of Android applications.

We believe that simple code with clear intents is the best way to achieve those goals.

Robert C. Martin wrote:

The ratio of time spent reading [code] versus writing is well over 10 to 1 [therefore] making it easy to read makes it easier to write.
While we all enjoy developing Android applications, we often wonder: Why do we always need to write the same code over and over? Why are our apps harder and harder to maintain? Context and Activity god objects, complexity of juggling with threads, hard to discover API, loads of anonymous listener classes, tons of unneeded casts... can't we improve that?

**How?**

Using Java annotations, developers can show their intent and let AndroidAnnotations generate the plumbing code at compile time.

**Features**

Dependency injection: inject views, extras, system services, resources, ...
Simplified threading model: annotate your methods so that they execute on the UI thread or on a background thread.
Event binding: annotate methods to handle events on views, no more ugly anonymous listener classes!
REST client: create a client interface, AndroidAnnotations generates the implementation.
No magic: As AndroidAnnotations generate subclasses at compile time, you can check the code to see how it works.
AndroidAnnotations provide those good things and even more for less than 50kb, without any runtime perf impact!

*Is your Android code easy to write, read, and maintain?*

Look at that:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.translate) // Sets content view to R.layout.translate
public class TranslateActivity extends Activity {

    @ViewById // Injects R.id.textInput
    EditText textInput;

    @ViewById(R.id.myTextView) // Injects R.id.myTextView
    TextView result;

    @AnimationRes // Injects android.R.anim.fade_in
    Animation fadeIn;

    @Click // When R.id.doTranslate button is clicked 
    void doTranslate() {
         translateInBackground(textInput.getText().toString());
    }

    @Background // Executed in a background thread
    void translateInBackground(String textToTranslate) {
         String translatedText = callGoogleTranslate(textToTranslate);
         showResult(translatedText);
    }

    @UiThread // Executed in the ui thread
    void showResult(String translatedText) {
         result.setText(translatedText);
         result.startAnimation(fadeIn);
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java annotations** bind specific conditions to be satisfied with code. Consider a scenario where we think we are overriding a method from anther class and we implemented code that (we think) is overriding the method. But if we somehow missed to exactly override one (e.g. we misspelled name. In superclass it was "mMethodOverridden" and we typed "mMethodoverridden"). The method will still compile and execute but it will not be doing what it should do.
So @Override is our way of telling Java to let us know if we are doing right thing. If we annotate a method with @override and it is not overriding anything, compiler will give us an error.
Other annotations work in a very similar way.

For more information, read docs [Lesson: annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are basically syntactic *metadata* that can be added to Java source code.Classes, methods, variables, parameters and packages may be annotated .

Metadata is data about data

**Why Were Annotations Introduced?**

Prior to annotation (and even after) XML were extensively used for metadata and somehow a particular set of Application Developers and Architects thought XML maintenance was getting troublesome. They wanted something which could be coupled closely with code instead of XML which is very loosely coupled (in some cases almost separate) from code. If you google “XML vs. annotations”, you will find a lot of interesting debates. Interesting point is XML configurations were introduced to separate configuration from code. Last two statements might create a doubt in your mind that these two are creating a cycle, but both have their pros and cons.

For eg:

@Override

It instructs the compiler to check parent classes for matching methods.